# C++ visual studio C2027 and C2011 errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors

I am working on a game engine and got those errors building:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status
> Error C2027 using undefined type 'AssetManager' SharkEngine F: \ Projects \ C ++ \ SharkEngine \ Text.h 10

and

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Deletion status
> Error C2011 'AssetManager': redefinition of type 'class' SharkEngine F: \ Projects \ C ++ \ SharkEngine \ AssetManager.h 8

I can't find why i am getting those errors.
Here is my code:

Text.h (where the C2027 error come from)

```
#pragma once
#include "AssetManager.h"

namespace Text
{
    sf::Text NewText(std::string str, std::string font, sf::Color color, int charSize, AssetManager* manager)
    {
        sf::Text t;
        t.setString(str);
        t.setFont(*manager->GetFont(font));
        t.setCharacterSize(charSize);
        t.setFillColor(color);
        return t;
    }
};
```

AssetManager.h (where the C2011 error come from)

```
#pragma once

#include<iostream>
#include<map>
#include<SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include<SFML/Audio.hpp>

class AssetManager
{
private:
    std::map<std::string, sf::Texture*> Textures;
    std::map<std::string, sf::Font*> Fonts;
    std::map<std::string, sf::SoundBuffer*> AudioClips;
public:
    void LoadDir(std::string path, bool absolutePath = false);
#define LoadAllAssets() LoadDir("");
    //texture
    void LoadTexture(std::string path, std::string name);
    sf::Texture* GetTexture(std::string name);
    //font
    void LoadFont(std::string path, std::string name);
    sf::Font* GetFont(std::string name);
    //sound buffer
    void LoadAudioClips(std::string path, std::string name);
    sf::SoundBuffer* GetAudioClips(std::string name);
};
```

Feel free to ask for any other information. Thank you for your time!

Comment: 10 and 8 are the line numbers? Thats `t.setFont(*manager->GetFont(font));` and `class AssetManager`. I guess you didn't post all contents of the files. In which lines are the errors?

Comment: Yes, thoses are the right lines, the problem is that the progran don't even want to build and that the files are loaded when the program is launched wich mean builed. More those error do not represent this type of problem. Thx for your idea.

Comment: Hi, I am sorry if I look impolite, so it's like this line: #include "AssetManager.h" in Text.h is not working properly?

Comment: urks sorry the politness thingy was a bad joke, nothing about you. Removed comment and post it again

Comment: I dont believe that your errors are from those lines in the code. For example in Text.h you use AssetManager already three lines above and if AssetManager is not declared that should trigger an error already. Please include a [mcve] and the complete error message

Comment: No problem, for real it is a problem on this website so thank for trying to help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finished to understand the problem, I found out that somewhere else in my code I did a wrong include (#include "SharkEngine/AssetManager.h" instead of "AssetManager.h").

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.